# Shortcut to access "end" button functionality on Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts

I am starting programming on a windows machine and since I'd been using a Mac for years, I'm totally fed up with hitting <kbd>end</kbd> button to get to the end of a line, because it's located incredibly far from the main part of the keyboard. This is completely irritating and makes writing code a tortue.

So the question is can I create a shortcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, witch would have the same functionality as <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> keys?